# Data Replication from MySql to Redis Server

Tags: java, spring-data-redis

I`m using RedisTemplate provided by spring framework for In-Memory caching. And MySql as primary database. I need to update the cache whenever new row is added or updated in primary database. 
How can i accomplish this using java? 
Is there any inbuilt feature provided by Redis server to achieve this?

**Update:**

```
@Override public void getEmployeeDetailsForRedisTemplate(List<Employee> employee) { 
  logger.info("Saving " + employee.size() + " record to redis template"); 
  for (Employee emp : employee) { 
    listOperations.leftPush(EnumConstants.EMPLOYEE_KEY.getValue(), emp); 
  } 
}
```

I have been polling database in regular interval and based on status column in DB i was pushing updated data to redis server. Which is not a efficient way of doing it

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post some code snippet that you have tried? even if it wasn't a successful one.

Comment: `@Override public void getEmployeeDetailsForRedisTemplate(List<Employee> employee) { logger.info("Saving " + employee.size() + " record to redis template"); for (Employee emp : employee) { listOperations.leftPush(EnumConstants.EMPLOYEE_KEY.getValue(), emp); } }`
I have been polling database in regular interval and based on status column in DB i was pushing updated data to redis server. Which is not a efficient way of doing it

Comment: I have put your code inside the question for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I wanted to ask whether there is a code snippet of the Java code that is invoked when a new row is added/updated but I am new so I can't comment

If you are using Redis as a cache then you might want to use `@Cacheable` annotation provided by `Spring-Data-Redis` by setting up `RedisCacheManager` in your configuration

> @Cacheable - Annotation indicating that the result of invoking a
>   method (or all methods in a class) can be cached. Each time an advised
>   method is invoked, caching behavior will be applied, checking whether
>   the method has been already invoked for the given arguments. A
>   sensible default simply uses the method parameters to compute the key,
>   but a SpEL expression can be provided via the key() attribute, or a
>   custom KeyGenerator implementation can replace the default one (see
>   keyGenerator()).
>
> If no value is found in the cache for the computed key, the target
>   method will be invoked and the returned value stored in the associated
>   cache. Note that Java8's Optional return types are automatically
>   handled and its content is stored in the cache if present.

So you could actually use it like

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "cacheName", key = "#employee.id")
public void getEmployeeDetailsForRedisTemplate(List<Employee> employee) { 
  logger.info("Saving " + employee.size() + " record to redis template"); 
  for (Employee emp : employee) { 
    listOperations.leftPush(EnumConstants.EMPLOYEE_KEY.getValue(), emp); 
  } 
}
```

Hope this helps